# How to update anaconda's version in pyenv

Tags: anaconda, pyenv

I'd like to know how to update anaconda in pyenv, inheriting third-party modules I installed to the former version.

I'm now using anaconda3-2.5.0 and would like to use anaconda3-4.0.0. I manage it with pyenv. If I just install the new version via pyenv, is the third party modules I installed inherited to the new version? How can I do that? Should I be careful to make a list of modules I installed, whenever I install a new module, in order to reinstall them at once to the environment(version).

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your existing python env isn't something `pyenv` can help you with, but it can help you manage a new python env using the latest Anaconda, and then you can reformulate that too match your needs.

There are two ways you could approach this problem;

1. update your `anaconda3-2.5.0` in place
2. create a new `anaconda3-4.0.0` and re-install what you need there.

Personally I prefer the second option as you can ensure that you environment is reproducible (for instance if you need to work on a new machine or with another developer), but I'll demonstrate both methods.

### 1. inplace update

Just use `conda` to update all your packages (including `anaconda`):

```
$ conda update -n <the name of your env> anaconda
$ conda update -n <the name of your env> python package_a package_b ...
```

etc.

`pyenv` will still believe that `anaconda3-2.5.0` is installed, but you'll know better.

### 2. new install

First get a record of what you've already installed in your python environment;

```
$ conda list --export > conda-requirements.txt
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then install the desired (new) python interpreter in `pyenv`

```
$ pyenv install anaconda3-4.0.0
```

and finally re-create your env setup

```
$ conda create -n <new env name> --file conda-requirements.txt
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```